# Unable to print the HTML lines from paragraph through queryselector from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage, queryselector

I wrote a rock, paper, scissor game and set the score in local storage using getItem and setItem .I wrote a paragraph with class=jsscore and tried to display the HTML content inside the script with a query selector but I couldn't do it. what am I doing wrong?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <title>video exercises</title>
     <body>
        <script>

            let score=
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem
            ('score')) ||{
                wins:0,
                losses:0,
                Ties:0
                }; 
              
            document.querySelector('.js-score').innerHTML = `wins: ${score.wins}, losses:       ${score.losses},Ties: ${score.Ties}`;
        
        
            function pickComputerMove()
            {
                const randomNumber= Math.random();

                if(randomNumber >=0 && randomNumber <1/3)
                {
                computerMove='rock';
                }

                else if(randomNumber >=1/3 && randomNumber <2/3)
                {
                computerMove='paper';
                }

                else if(randomNumber >=2/3 && randomNumber <1)
                {
                    computerMove='scissors';
                }

                return computerMove;

            }
            function playGame(playerMove){
                const computerMove=pickComputerMove();
            
                let result='';
                if(playerMove === 'scissors')
                {
                    if(computerMove === 'rock')
                    {
                        result='you lose';
                    }

                    else if(computerMove ==='paper')
                    {
                        result='you win';
                    }

                    else if(computerMove ==='scissors')
                    {
                        result='Tie';
                    }

                    if(result === 'you win'){
                        score.wins +=1;
                    }

                    else if(result === 'you lose'){
                        score.losses +=1;
                    }

                    else if(result ==='Tie'){
                        score.Ties +=1;
                    }

                    localStorage.setItem('score',JSON.stringify(score));
                    
                    alert(`you picked ${playerMove},
                    computer picked ${computerMove},${result}
                    wins: ${score.wins},losses: ${score.losses},Ties: ${score.Ties}`);
                }

                else if(playerMove ==='rock')
                {
                    if(computerMove ==='rock')
                    {
                        result='Tie';
                    }
                    else if(computerMove ==='paper')
                    {
                        result='you lose';
                    }
                    else if(computerMove ==='scissors')
                    {
                        result='you win';
                    }
                    if(result === 'you win'){
                        score.wins +=1;
                    }
                    else if(result === 'you lose'){
                        score.losses +=1;
                    }
                    else if(result ==='Tie'){
                        score.Ties +=1;
                    }
                    alert(`you picked ${playerMove},
                    computer picked ${computerMove},${result}
                    wins: ${score.wins},losses: ${score.losses},Ties: ${score.Ties}`);
                }
                
                else if(playerMove ==='paper')
                {
                    if(computerMove ==='rock')
                    {
                        result='you win';
                    }

                    else if(computerMove ==='paper')
                    {
                        result='Tie';
                    }

                    else if(computerMove ==='scissors')
                    {
                        result='you loose';
                    }

                    if(result === 'you win'){
                        score.wins +=1;
                    }

                    else if(result === 'you loose'){
                        score.losses +=1;
                    }

                    else if(result ==='Tie'){
                        score.Ties +=1;
                    }
                    alert(`you picked ${playerMove},
                    computer picked ${computerMove},${result}
                    wins: ${score.wins},losses: ${score.losses},Ties: ${score.Ties}`);
                }
               

            }
            
            </script>
            <button onclick="
            playGame('rock');
            ">Rock</button>

        <button onclick="
        playGame('paper');
        ">paper</button>

        <button onclick="
        playGame('scissors');
        ">scissors</button>
        
        <p class="js-score"></p>
        <button onclick="
        score.wins=0;
        score.losses=0;
        score.Ties=0;
                localStorage.removeItem('score');
        ">Reset score</button>
   </body>
   </html>
    
            
    </body>
    </html>
```

I also added an extra button called restore button,it restores and sets all the values to zero

Comment: Place the script just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: can I please know why the script didn't work when not next to the </body> tag?

Comment: The elements it was looking for weren't in the DOM yet.